# how to find the dynamic xpath (changes every time when reload the page)

Tags: javascript, xpath, css-selectors, puppeteer

Hello guys i need help to solve this, im trying to make a automation to login in Nike BR website (that is different from the others), but everytime that i reload the page the xpath keeps changing anyone could help me with this problem? appreciate you guys
the website is https://www.nike.com.br/
you need to click in "Login / Inscreva-se" then the inputs will load

```
const puppeteer = require ('puppeteer');
const login = '//*[@id="anchor-acessar-unite-oauth2"]';
const emailinput = 'changing xpath'
const passwordinput = 'changing xpath'
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    
   
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1080});
    await page.goto ('https://www.nike.com.br');
    const login= await page.waitForXPath('//*[@id="anchor-acessar-unite-oauth2"]');
    await login.click();
    const emailinput = await page.type('changing xpath', 'myEmail@outlook.com', { delay: 110 });
    const passwordinput = await page.type('changing xpath', 'myEmail@outlook.com', { delay: 110 });

    

    

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use the dynamic parts and select the elements by something that's not changing between reloads. These should work as far as I can tell.

Selecting the e-mail address input box:

```
const emailinput = await page.type('//input[@name="emailAddress"]', 'myEmail@outlook.com', { delay: 110 });
```

Selecting the password input box:

```
const passwordinput = await page.type('//input[@name="password"]', 'password', { delay: 110 });
```

**Update**

Now I see why the above won't work straight away. The reason is that the content you're trying to select is not in the top frame, but in an iframe.

To make it work you'll need to modify your script to

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1080 });
  await page.goto('https://www.nike.com.br');
  const login = await page.waitForXPath('//*[@id="anchor-acessar-unite-oauth2"]');
  await login.click();

  const frameElement = await page.waitForXPath('//iframe[@id="nike-unite-oauth2-iframe"]');
  const frame = await frameElement.contentFrame();

  const emailInput = await frame.waitForXPath('//input[@name="emailAddress"]');
  const passwordInput = await frame.waitForXPath('//input[@name="password"]');
  await emailInput.evaluate((elem) => elem.value = 'myEmail@outlook.com');
  await passwordInput.evaluate((elem) => elem.value = 'password');
})();
```

I changed `type` to `evaluate` to directly assign the value. I've found `type` to be unreliable and didn't have time to figure out why.

**Update 2**

To also click on the login button you can add this to the end:

```
const submitInput = await frame.waitForXPath('//div[contains(@class, "loginSubmit")]/input', { visible: true });
await submitInput.click();
```

Comment: Really appreciate!!!! i was about a few days trying to do this, you could help me one more time please? i tried to use await page.keyboard.press('Enter'); to finish the login but it doesnt work but thanks in advance!!!

Comment: i need to click in the "ENTRAR" button but i dont see a way to do this, if you could help me i'll be very grateful!

Comment: @Murilo You're welcome. Please upvote and/or accept the answer if it worked for you

Comment: all right! in this time i cant upvote because i dont have 15 reputation but appreciate your help so much!!! I have just one question if isnt to much to answer this, but do you develop bots?

Comment: @Murilo I see, no problem :) No, I don't develop bots.